# Running Java Program from Folder Mac with Terminal

Tags: java, macos, class, terminal, directory

So I'm used to creating a single Java file and putting it into the desktop and running it from the terminal on mac (`cd Desktop/`, `javac HelloWorld.java`, `java HelloWorld`). Now I have a program that has multiple classes. My question is how to run a program from a folder. I have around 5 .java files in my folder and I need to run the one with the main class.

Comment: Whilst not a direct answer to your question, it's times like these I'd recommend moving to an IDE.

Comment: @Rogue But I think one should know how to use terminal. It's a basic thing in learning. Learning without using IDE makes concepts strong and can learn many things( **I Think**) like below [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38810333/4859791).

Comment: Oh absolutely. But learning it in a terminal is just more motivation to avoid it from my own experience, hah.

Answer (score 1):

Writing multiple classes in single file or writing them in different .java files changes nothing. Finally, you have no. of .class files equal to no. of classes you have defined in your .java files.

The JVM checks for the `public static void main(String[] args)` in your class file to run the program(BTW you can also overload it but the above one is what is called first). You can also write `main()` method in every class. I believe that's why you use class name to run the program like `java HelloWorld`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the name of the entry point class instead of HelloWorld, other classes will be compiled and used automatically.

The entry point class is the one that contains method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```